# AWS Lambda test does not return data from DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to get data from my DynamoDB table called dashboard so I am testing out the Lambda function with a sample from the table.

But all I am getting back from the test is :

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}
```

It should just return the data from the table that matches it based on the ID as that is what I use to partition the table.

**Dashboard example data which is also the test I made**

```
{
  "batteryLevel": 35,
  "deviceId": "yxftd9pnitd-156xhref9g69a",
  "eventId": "c07e3f9f-f6bb-4792-be6f-a9be95cdff38",
  "id": 12345,
  "location": {
    "accuracy": 35.369,
    "latitude": 55.8256671,
    "longitude": 37.5962931
  },
  "tags": [
    {
      "accelX": 0.012,
      "accelY": -0.004,
      "accelZ": 1.008,
      "createDate": "2020-08-11T18:51:58+0300",
      "dataFormat": 5,
      "defaultBackground": 2,
      "favorite": true,
      "humidity": 32.8425,
      "id": "E5:F1:98:34:C0:0F",
      "measurementSequenceNumber": 62865,
      "movementCounter": 21,
      "name": "Kitchen",
      "pressure": 98702,
      "rssi": -43,
      "temperature": 25.58,
      "txPower": 4,
      "updateAt": "2020-08-18T19:57:48+0300",
      "voltage": 3.013
    }
  ],
  "time": "2020-08-18T19:57:48+0300"
}
```

**Lambda Function**

```
"use strict";

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({ region: "ap-southeast-1" });

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: "2012-10-08" });
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "ap-southeast-1"});
    
    const params = {
        TableName: "dashboard",
        Key: {
            id: 12345
        }
    };
    try {
        const data = await documentClient.get(params);
        console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
   }
};
```

Comment: Seems like you are executing either wrong function or wrong version of it.

Comment: I just checked and its using the latest version.

Comment: You are outputting `Hello from Lambda`. This is not coming from the function you've posted. Maybe you did not deploy the function?

Comment: Wow yeah that fixed can't believe I forgot to deploy it.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **not deploying** the function after adding new code. Subsequently, the previously deployed version (i.e. "Hello from Lambda") was being executed.

The **solution** was to deploy the new function.